# How to access table tokens in views through handler

Tags: tokens, views

I've added a custom field of type global using views_handler_field. This custom field type is basically a button that needs to call a javascript function. This javascript function takes an adjacent field's value as a parameter. When I edit the view on my webpage, under rewrite rules->replacement values, I can see the token for the value I need in my handler's functionality. In the code example, it's [fieldID]

However, I don't see any way to access this value in my views_handler_field include file.

```
function render($values) {

    $actions = array();
    $variable = variable_get('fieldID'); // HERE is what I'd like to do to get the adjacent [fieldID] icon

    $alt = t('Download File');
    $actions[] = array(
      'name' => t('Download'),
      'html' => 'javascript:initiateDownload('.$variable.')',     
      'id' => t('download-button-' . $variable),
      'icon' => theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'download_process') . '/images/edit.png', 'alt' => $alt))
    );

    $output = '';

    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($actions as $action) {
      $output .= l($action['icon'], $action['html'], array('attributes' => array('id' => $action['id'] . $counter), 'html' => TRUE, 'external' => TRUE));
      $counter++;
    }
    return $output;
  }
  function query() {

  }
```

I've tried working with get_render_tokens, but I don't think that that's what I'm looking for. Any help here would be appreciated! For reference, I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being very simple. All I needed to do was cast $values to an array, then access the id. Like this:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($values), true);
$value = $array['fieldid'];
```